# Environment Variable to change build

Tags: build

Is there a way to get the build to see an environment variable so that all the files can be built differently with one Environment variable change.  Such as

```
#ifdef UseFirstDir
    #include <C:\MyFirstDir\ImportantIncludes.h>
#else
    #include <C:\MySecondDir\ImportantIncludes.h>
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not environment, no.

If you have access to the compilation command line you can do the equivalent of `#define` from there:

```
avr-gcc ... blah blah ... -DUseFirstDir
```

That is most effective if you are using a *Makefile* build system rather than relying on the Arduino IDE which doesn't give you access to those kind of things without modifying the core configuration, which isn't nice, and certainly is neither permanent nor flexible (doesn't survive upgrades to new versions, and isn't easy to turn on and off at will).

A better IDE, though, can do it. Facilities for setting control flags like that exist within [UECIDE](http://uecide.org) and it's possible to tie them to menu entries to make switching options on and off easier. It's not documented how to do it though (yet).

Or you can just have a list of `#define` options at the top of your sketch:

```
/* Uncomment this to use the first directory. */
// #define UseFirstDir

// .... later ....

#ifdef UseFirstDir
    #include <C:\MyFirstDir\ImportantIncludes.h>
#else
    #include <C:\MySecondDir\ImportantIncludes.h>
#endif
```

Comment: I have Cygwin, but the command line (bash or dos) is not finding avr-gcc.  The second option seems best for now.

Comment: @Gregg I have just [blogged about adding menu entries for a sketch in UECIDE.](https://uecide.wordpress.com/2016/12/21/adding-menu-options-to-a-sketch/).